# ransackを使用してsearch.html.erb(検索結果）を表示させたいです　検索ボタンを押すと初期画面のindex.html.erbが表示されてしまいます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ソースコード

ルーティング

```
get "search", to: "posts#search"
```

検索フォーム

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: search_path do |f| %>
<%= f.search_field :shopaddress_cont, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "住所を入れてください" %>
<%= f.submit'検索',class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

コントローラー

```
before_action :set_q, only: [:index, :search]

    def index
      @posts = Post.all
      @post = Post.new
      @kaminari= Post.all.page(params[:page]).per(6)
    end
    
    def search
      @results = @q.result
    end

private

    def set_q
      @q = Post.ransack(params[:q])
    end
```

```
# Strong Parameter
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:shopname, :shopaddress, 
                               :shopcontent)
 end
```

表示させたいview

search.html.erb

```
<tbody>
<% @results.each do |searchresult| %>
<div class = "searchresultbox"></div>
<br><%= searchresult.shopname %></br>
<br><%= searchresult.shopaddress %></br>
<br><%= searchresult.shopcontent %></br>
</div>

<% end %>
</tbody>
```

初期画面全体view(検索フォーム含む）

```
<div class="navbar-brand"><%= link_to 'ピックアップしに行ったらこんなところで 
  した', root_path %><i class="fab fa-uber"></i></div>


<form class="form-inline">
  近くのお店を調べてみる
  <%= search_form_for @q, url: search_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :shopaddress_cont, class: 'form-control', 
    placeholder: "住所を入れてください" %>
    <%= f.submit'検索',class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %>
</form>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 50rem;" >
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <% @posts.each do |post| %>
         <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success mt-5 
           border-left border-right"><%= post.shopname %></div>
         <div class="list-group-item border-left border-right"> 
           <%= post.shopaddress %></div>
         <div class="list-group-item border-left border-right 
           border-bottom" style="height: 8rem;"><%= 
           post.shopcontent %></div>
       <% end %>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

検索ボタン押した際のログ
Started GET "/" for 103.5.140.166 at 2021-07-29 23:44:32 +0000
Cannot render console from 103.5.140.166! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`
↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:19
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts`
↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:32
Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 22.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Comment: コントローラーに認証によるリダイレクトなどは入っているでしょうか？ブラウザのdeveloper toolsなどを利用して `/search` に移動しているか、その後リダイレクトされていないかを確認した方が良さそうです

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。indexにrenderされてました。Rendering posts/index.html.erb 　　いまいち原因がわからないのですが、お手数なのですが、助力していただきたいです

Comment: 例えば検索フォームのコードが他のフォームの入れ子になっていたりしませんか？可能なら検索フォームのビューとコントローラーのコードをすべて掲載してほしいです。現状の内容だけなら問題ないように見えます

Comment: また `Rendering posts/index.html.erb` の前に `GET "/search?` などのログはありませんか？検索ボタンを押したタイミングで出力されるrailsログも掲載いただけるなら判断材料になります

Comment: 返信ありがとおございます‍♂️。今、追記しましたのでぜひ見て欲しいです。確かに他のフォームの入れ子になってるかもしれないです。確認します。アドバイスありがとうございます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search_form_for` のフォームヘルパーがformタグを出力するので外側で囲うタグを削除して試してみてください。

```rb
<%= search_form_for @q, url: search_path, class: "form-inline" do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "近くのお店を調べてみる" %>
  <%= f.search_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "please name" %>
  <%= f.submit "検索", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます！！無事解決できました。

Comment: 今回の場合は、認識としては、htmlのフォームに値が入力されていたので、rails側で、なにも入力されてないということで、初期画面にrenderされたという認識で大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: formタグが入れ子になった際の仕様は把握していませんが、外側のformタグの方が検索ボタンで実行されたと推測されます。action属性が指定なしなので現在のURLに対してアクション実行されたのでしょう

Comment: 解決と理解まで回答してくださりありがとうございます‍♂️